# JSONPath for Root element

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-step-functions, json-path-expression

I'm using [JSONPath](https://docs.hevodata.com/sources/streaming/rest-api/writing-jsonpath-expressions/) in AWS Step Functions ([playground: Parameters tab](https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/states/home?region=eu-west-1#/simulator)).

In this example if we have a JSON input:

```
{
  "movies": [
    {
      "genre": "crime",
      "director": "Quentin Tarantino",
      "title": "Reservoir Dogs",
      "year": 1992
    },
    {
      "genre": "action",
      "director": "Brian De Palma",
      "title": "Mission: Impossible",
      "year": 1996,
      "staring": [
        "Tom Cruise"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "lastUpdated": "2020-05-27T08:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "stringJson": "{\"arr\": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], \"bool\": true, \"null\": null, \"number\": 1}"
}
```

and parameters like this:

```
{
    "test.$": "$.metadata"
}
```

we would get this output:

```
{
  "test": {
    "lastUpdated": "2020-05-27T08:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
```

while I would like to get

```
{
  "lastUpdated": "2020-05-27T08:00:00.000Z"
}
```

or even better, say all but one:

```
{
  "movies": [
    {
      "genre": "crime",
      "director": "Quentin Tarantino",
      "title": "Reservoir Dogs",
      "year": 1992
    },
    {
      "genre": "action",
      "director": "Brian De Palma",
      "title": "Mission: Impossible",
      "year": 1996,
      "staring": [
        "Tom Cruise"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "lastUpdated": "2020-05-27T08:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
```

How do I put an element (or all elements) in the root?

I tried parameters like:

```
{
    "$": "$.metadata.lastUpdated"
}
```

or

```
{
    "$": "$.(?[@ != 'stringJson'])"
}
```

but none of these worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Set `InputPath` to `$.metadata` to get:

```json
{
  "lastUpdated": "2020-05-27T08:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Reference paths (the type of path that `InputPath` accepts) is limited in that it can only identify a single node within the entire JSON structure.

You can't natively exclude all elements except 'x' element.